# Condensing jquery numbered functions

Tags: jquery, function

Im sure this has probably been answered already but im not quite sure what Im asking so if you can point me in the right direction that would be much apreciated.

OK so i have a function that all but the id number is the same up to 30

is there a way i can do this without repeating it 30 times

example below

```
$('ul#grid li#project_001 a').click(function(){ 
$('.colOne').html(ajax_load).load('ajax/project_001.html');
}); 

$('ul#grid li#project_002 a').click(function(){ 
$('.colOne').html(ajax_load).load('ajax/project_002.html');
});

$('ul#grid li#project_003 a').click(function(){ 
$('.colOne').html(ajax_load).load('ajax/project_003.html');
}); 

$('ul#grid li#project_004 a').click(function(){ 
$('.colOne').html(ajax_load).load('ajax/project_004.html');
});
```

thanks for your help guys

Comment: You can modify your html or not?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work:

```
$('#grid li[id^="project_"] a').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).closest('li').attr('id');

    $('.colOne').html(ajax_load).load('ajax/' + id + '.html');
});
```

Although I would use classes and add `data-` attributes to those `<li>` elements:

```
<li class="project" data-filename="ajax/project_004.html">
```

And use the `.data()` function:

```
$('#grid li.project a').click(function() {
    var filename = $(this).closest('li').data('filename');

    $('.colOne').html(ajax_load).load(filename);
});
```

Comment: brilliant thanks, really useful stuff ill try it out straight away and let you know how i get on, thanks :)

Comment: Hey guys thanks for all your help i think im gonna end up using jeffs version actually, but have a look at your  knowledge in action thanks
http://danielwakefield.co.uk/test3.html

Answer (score 1):

You want to do a match on attribute:

```
$('ul#grid li[id^="project_"] a').click(function(){

    var id = $(this).closest('li').attr('id');

    $('.colOne').html(ajax_load).load('ajax/'+id+'.html');
});
```

`[id^="project_"]` says `has an attribute that starts with "project_"`.

Although you would be better off making a class, and then using a data attribute to store the number:

```
<li class="project" data-projnum="004">...
```

JS:

```
$('ul#grid li.project a').click(function(){ 

    var projnum = $(this).closest('li').data('projnum');

    $('.colOne').html(ajax_load).load('ajax/project_' + projnum + '.html');
});
```

Comment: both brilliant solutions, decided in my particular case to go with blenders solution simply because it gives me the flexibility to name the corresponding urls anything i like, rather then them being strictly tied to incrementing IDs even though jeffs solution is that bit cleaner, but I can certainly see how both are very powerful and I have learnt allot from these two methods, thanks so much guys brilliant work